# How to use the counter in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to store values in sessionStorage. The code below works fine, but I would like to use a loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#leksjon_submit").click(function(){  
        sessionStorage.svar_15_1=document.getElementById("spm_15_1").value;
        sessionStorage.svar_15_2=document.getElementById("spm_15_2").value;
        sessionStorage.svar_15_3=document.getElementById("spm_15_3").value;
        sessionStorage.svar_15_4=document.getElementById("spm_15_4").value;
        sessionStorage.svar_15_5=document.getElementById("spm_15_5").value;
    });
});
```

This one of my many unsucessful attempts to use a loop. It does not work. Nothing is saved in sessionStorage. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#leksjon_submit").click(function(){
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            sessionStorage.svar_15_[i]=document.getElementById("spm_15_")+i.value;  
            }
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `i` as your counter like this:  But when you're accessing a value in an object using a variable you need to use bracket notation.

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    sessionStorage['svar_15_'+i]=document.getElementById("spm_15_"+i).value;  
}
```

Comment: This was my first question on this site. I got a perfect cut & paste solution in no time. Amazing. Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on your bracket notation

```
sessionStorage["svar_15_" + i] = document.getElementById("spm_15_"+i).value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setItem()`method:

`sessionStorage.setItem('svar_15_' + i, document.getElementById('spm_15' + i).value);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Don't forget to declare your loop variables.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  var key = 'svar_15_' + i;
  var id = 'spm_15_' + i;
  sessionStorage[key] = document.getElementById(id).value;  
}
```